# @Value property is returning null in the spring component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have created a validator component in spring boot and I am keeping a regex expression in the `application.properties`. I have used `@Value` annotation to get the value of regex in my component and I am compiling the Pattern outside any method or constructor and that is giving me null pointer exception as the regex is not getting it's value at that time. But when I move the pattern to some method, it's working fine. Why is that?
Why is @Value not working even though object is created using @Component

Look at the code below:

Code returning NullPointerException:

```
@Component
public class ValidString implements ConstraintValidator<ValidString, String> {

  @Value("${user.input.regex}")
  private String USER_INPUT_REGEX;

  private Pattern USER_INPUT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(USER_INPUT_REGEX);

  @Override
  public boolean validate(String userInput, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    return USER_INPUT_PATTERN.matcher(userInput).find();
  }
}
```

Code working fine:

```
@Component
public class ValidString implements ConstraintValidator<ValidString, String> {

  @Value("${user.input.regex}")
  private String USER_INPUT_REGEX;

  private Pattern USER_INPUT_PATTERN;

  @Override
  public boolean validate(String userInput, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    USER_INPUT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(USER_INPUT_REGEX);
    return USER_INPUT_PATTERN.matcher(userInput).find();
  }
}
```

Also if you could explain why the first one is not working and second one is working, that'd be great.

application.properties

```
user.input.regex = ^[a-zA-Z0-9/\\-_ \\s+]*$
```

Comment: Please show your application.properties file

Comment: Ditch the `String` field and just put the annotation on the `Pattern` field. Spring will handle the conversion for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Field initializers (first example in question) are executed *during* the class constructor execution. `@Value` is injected by Spring *after* the constructor returns, using reflection. This means that you cannot have initializers using `@Value`-injected values.

The issue can be resolved by constructor or setter injection:

```java
// Inject using constructor
@Component
public class ValidString implements ConstraintValidator<ValidString, String> {

  private Pattern USER_INPUT_PATTERN;

  @Autowired
  public ValidString(@Value("${user.input.regex}") String regex) {
    this.USER_INPUT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(regex);
  }
```

```java
// Inject using setter method
@Component
public class ValidString implements ConstraintValidator<ValidString, String> {

  private Pattern USER_INPUT_PATTERN;

  @Autowired
  private void setUserInputRegex(@Value("${user.input.regex}") String regex) {
    this.USER_INPUT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(regex);
  }
```

Comment: Even better, Spring will do the conversion just add the `@Value` on a `Pattern` field and Spring will handle the conversion for you. No need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern USER_INPUT_PATTERN is before spring process.
the class ValidString object initial order is: ->process field initial->constructor -> inject field
so, when you use 1 code, it must be null point, because field has no inject